# Matlab: Element size error?

Tags: matlab

```
clc
clear
N=10;
dE=0;

demonEnergy=0;
systemEnergy=-10;
ring=ones(10,1);
temp=zeros(1,10000);
demonAcc=zeros(1,10000);
start=1;

for i = 1:+1: 10000,    
    random=randi(10,1);
    newSpin=-ring(random);
    ring(random)=newSpin;
    dE=2*newSpin*(ring*(mod(random+1,10))+ring*(mod(random+9,10)));

        if dE<0
            demonEnergy=demonEnergy+abs(dE);
            systemEnergy=systemEnergy-abs(dE);
        elseif demonEnergy>=dE
            systemEnergy=systemEnergy+abs(dE);
            demonEnergy=demonEnergy-abs(dE);
        end

    demonAcc(i)=dE;   
    temp(i)=-1/(atanh(demonAcc(i)));  %J=1
    dE=0;
end
```

Error:

> In an assignment A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be
>   the same.
>
> Error in PlotTest1 (line 29) demonAcc(i)=dE;

Now, I don't see why that is not allowed. I'm setting an element of my Array equal to a number of the same size. Something that comes to mind is that, maybe I can't set it equal to a negative number, but I tried a test outside my loop and it works perfectly. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suspect your error is in the `dE=2*newSpin...` line. You are multiplying `ring*(...)` in two places where I think you want to index into `ring`. As your code stands, `dE` will have size `(10, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks.. thats such a stupid mistake. But, now I get this "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in PlotTest1 (line 19)
    dE=2*newSpin*(ring(mod(random+1,10))+ring(mod(random+9,10)));"

Comment: The mod function can return 0 and 0 cannot be an array index.

Comment: Is there a quick way to fix this? It's usually fine for C++ for example, since arrays start from 0.

Comment: Actually, just to test my code I added +1 at the end. Now, I tried to plot demonEnergy vs temp, but I got nothing in the graph. Apparently demonAcc(i)=dE takes 0 not dE...

Comment: Please explain `dE=2*newSpin*(ring*(mod(random+1,10))+ring*(mod(random+9,10)));`. What are you trying to achieve? Is dE expected to be a matrix? or a single value?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the intentions behind

```
dE=2*newSpin*(ring*(mod(random+1,10))+ring*(mod(random+9,10)));
```

I am assuming that `dE` is a single value. Currently which is not. Currently `dE` is a matrix of size `10x1`. So cant perform

```
demonAcc(i)=dE;
```

because you cant put `dE` which is a matrix of size `10x1` into a `demonAcc(i)` which is expecting a single value. Otherwise you will have to change it to matrix like this

```
demonAcc(:,i)=dE;
```

Then `demonAcc` size will become `10x10000`. Which is currently `1x10000`.

```
demonAcc=zeros(1,10000);
```

will change to

```
demonAcc=zeros(10,10000);
```

also `dE` will become `dE(j)` which is inside another loop in the below code

```
if dE<0
            demonEnergy=demonEnergy+abs(dE);
            systemEnergy=systemEnergy-abs(dE);
        elseif demonEnergy>=dE
            systemEnergy=systemEnergy+abs(dE);
            demonEnergy=demonEnergy-abs(dE);
        end
```

Everything depends on if `dE` is matrix or a single value. 
If `dE` is a single value update

```
    dE=2*newSpin*(ring*(mod(random+1,10))+ring*(mod(random+9,10)));
```

to give a single value `dE` and your error will gone.